# Animation Rigging stops working when transitioning between animations

Tags: unity, animation, rigging, inverse-kinematics

I've followed all the online guides, I've changed characters (from a character taken from the Unity Asset Store to one from Mixamo), I've used animations taken from three different sites, but the problem remains.

Between one animation and another, the character does not keep aiming at the target (see images). It does the same thing also with the classic transitions (not the blend tree), as long as there is only one animation the IK is correct and points to the target, as soon as it mixes between one animation and the other it points to the top right.

**This is the correct position (`MoveX=0` and `MoveY=1` only one animation running)**

[image]

---

**This is the wrong position (`MoveX=0` and `MoveY=0.61` merging of two animations)**

[image]

The structure of the Rig seems correct to me. Can you give me an indication of what to look at? if you need more information just ask.

**This is my structure tree**

[image]

Thanks for your help.

**UPDATE**

I tried to look into the problem. And to make it easier for those who want to help me I made a video explaining the problem.

[Youtube video](https://youtu.be/4KwC8BQXqtw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by switching from the Unity version `2022.2.1f1` to the beta version `2023.1.0b12`. I don't know which of the intermediate versions solves this problem, but at least in the current beta version it works fine.